# Regarding 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 associations in UML

Tags: associations, uml, multiplicity

Just want to know how can we differentiate the multiplicities 0..* and 1..*.

For example:

```
 ---------             ---------
|         |0..*   0..*|         |
|CLASS    |-----------| STUDENT |
|         |           |         |
 ---------             ---------
```

For this, if we put 1..* in class object, I can see that both represent the same behaviour. Is that right?

0..* --->  Zero or more classes can have zero or more students,
which means a class or more classes can have more students or no students. (excluded no class behaviour)

1..* ---> One or more classes can have zero or more students,
which means a class or more classes can have more students or no students.

Please correct my understanding?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to read it the other way around.

If you have `1..*` on the `Class` end that means that a `Student` has at least 1 and possible more `Classes`.

`0..*` on the `Class` end means that a student could also have no `Classes` at all.

Comment: Thank you... Clearly understand the difference now.